# Rendering XML attribute value in page

Tags: css, xml, firefox, rendering

I am trying to render a complex XML document as webpage(FF only) using a stylesheet. In one of the tag the content itself is part of the a attribute value

```
  <projectMember>
    <Role roleType="CHANGE ADMINISTRATOR III"/>
  </projectMember>
  <projectMember>
    <Role roleType="CHANGE ADMINISTRATOR I"/>
  </projectMember>
```

I need to display the value of roleType in Firefox using css selectors. I dont want to use XLST or Javascript as modifying XML source is last option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use "content" and the attr css function.
To see a similar solution used to print the href of a link after the link in print media, goto http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/ and scroll down the page to the heading "Printed links"

it might look something like this in the end:

```
 content: attr(roleType);
```

Comment: But for some reason content attr is not consistently working in deeply nested structure :(. +1 for the link